# CTCI: "Given a circular linked list, implement an algorithm that returns the node at the beginning of the loop"

Tags: loops, linked-list

I looked at other posts here in regards to the same CTCI question, but nothing addresses the particular problem I have when trying to understand how to solve this. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479058/hare-and-tortoise-algorithm-why-is-the-collision-spot-and-head-of-linked-list-a) question comes close, but the answer is still confusing me.

For some summary of the problem:

The solution in the book first says that I should have two pointers, one 'fast' and one 'slow' where the fast pointer moves two steps an iteration whereas the slow just moves a single step. The author argues that if it takes k total steps for the slow pointer to enter the loop, the fast pointer has moved 2k steps in.

Said differently, this means that when the slow pointer is 0 steps from the node, the fast pointer moves k steps, but since there's the potential that k is larger than the size of the loop, I really should be considered with k % loop_size.

This is my first question, the author writes that we're capital K steps in with K being defined as k % loop_size. I get that I'm loop_size - k steps from the head when the slow enters, meaning I collide at whatever node is loop_size - k steps into the loop, or K steps before the loop, but the answer doesn't explain to me why exactly being K steps from the loop means that I will also enter the start of the loop after k steps too. That is, if it takes k % loop_size steps to get back into the start of the loop why am I guaranteed that I will be at the start at k steps too?

Comment: From the description I think it is not a circular linked list. It's a linked list which might have a loop init and you have to find if it exists or not. and if yes you have to find the starting point. This is solved using floyd's loop detection algorithm. A good explanation is here. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10360/floyds-cycle-detection-algorithm-determining-the-starting-point-of-cycle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hare and tortoise algorithm. Why is the collision spot and head of linked list at the same distance of the start of the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479058/hare-and-tortoise-algorithm-why-is-the-collision-spot-and-head-of-linked-list-a)